# Parsing json data list in python

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm a beginner coding a home project.  I've used json to store some information and now I've opened it from another python function to use, here is what is returned:

```
{'_id': {'$oid': '5eab443d1eae7f1c689ab614'}, 'a': 'James', 'answer1': 'c', 'answer2': 'a', 'answer3': 'b', 'answer4': 'c', 'answer5': 'b', 'b': 'John', 'c': 'Jake', 'd': 'a house', 'e': 'a caravan', 'f': 'a hotel', 'g': 'red', 'h': 'orange', 'i': 'yellow', 'j': 'hat', 'k': 'scarf', 'l': "gloves", 'm': 'happy', 'n': 'sad', 'o': 'upset', 'q1': '1', 'q2': '2', 'q3': '3', 'q4': '4', 'q5': '5', 'question1': 'The boy's name was:', 'question2': 'The boy lived in:', 'question3': 'The boy's jumper was:', 'question4': 'The boy lost his:', 'question5': 'The boy was:', 'quiz_id': '1a', 'quiz_title': 'The New Boy', 'url': '/images/comp_cards/card1a.png'}
```

Now, I am trying to pull information from this list but all the info is stored at the 0 index so when I do this:

```
with open('quiz.json', 'r') as read_file: 
    quiz_data = json.load(read_file) 

    print(quiz_data[0])
```

the whole lot is returned, if I change the index value to above 0 then nothing is returned.  What do I need to do to retrieve only data from the list that I need, so say I need the fields name 'answer1', 'answer2' and 'answer3'? thanks

Answer (score 0):

since output is a dictionary ,you can access to key and get the value.For example if you need value of answer1 you can try

```
quiz_data[0].get("answer1")
```

or

```
quiz_data[0]["answer1"]
```

Comment: Hi, when I try quiz_data.get("answer1") I get AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'and when I use quiz_data["answer1"] I get TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices not str

Comment: Not too sure what you mean so hopefully this helps.  The data is stored in a mongodb which I then get from (don't know how to put this in code brackets so apologies)        @app.route("/quizstart", methods=["GET","POST"])
def quizstart():
    quiz_id = request.form.get('quiz_id')
    quizzes = Comp_cards1.objects.filter(quiz_id=quiz_id)
    
    with open('quiz.json', 'w') as f:  # writing JSON object
        json.dump(quizzes, f)  
        
    return render_template("quizstart.html", quizzes=quizzes, quiz_id=quiz_id)

Comment: after you load the json data from file it is stored in quiz_data variable.quiz_data is a list which 0th index have all the data as a dictionary,is this correct?

Comment: that's it now, thank you o much, I had a sore head for 2 hours trying to figure thsi out!